# Cant see explosion in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

When I look at my explosion in the *3D Viewport* I see this:

[image: in Viewport]

But when I go into render mode, I see a black rectangular prism. How would I go about making it so when I render I see the explosion

Answer (score 3):

In blender cycles, you have to use attributes in the node editor to make flames and/or smoke visible.

This Image shows is an example of how you need to set up your smoke.
To add flames and make them look good, you can follow this video tutorial.

https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-fire-cycles/

[image: Sample Image]

Much fun!